# Remove checkbox from parent node in TreeView from

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, gijgo-treeview

I am using Gijgo library (https://gijgo.com/tree/demos/material-design-treeview-checkbox) to display items in tree. I do not want to have checkbox beside the parent node (marked red in the image). Can anyone help me with this please?

This is how I am displaying the tree structure:

```
        var tree2 = $('#tree').tree({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            dataSource: '/products/getcategoriestree/' + get_configurator_id(),
            iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
            primaryKey: 'id',
            checkboxes: true,                
            icons: {
                expand: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
                collapse: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>'
            }, dataBound: function (e) {
                tree2.expandAll();
            }
        });
```

I tried using nodeDatBound function to iterate each node, and I can grab each parent item for which I do not want to have checkbox, but I am not sure how to remove checkbox from specific nodes.

```
        tree2.on('nodeDataBound', function (e, node, id, record) {                
            if (record["children"] != null) {
                console.log("PARENT Record");
                console.log(record);
                console.log(node);
                node.enableCheckBox = false;
            }
        });
```

[image]

P.S. I can't change the library, it's part of legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS override the existing style:

```
<style>
   div[data-type="tree"] > ul > li[data-role="node"] > div[data-role="wrapper"] > span[data-role="checkbox"] {
      display: none !important;
   }
</style>
```

You could also use `querySelectorAll` in JavaScript to do something similar. I'm using a more generic selector here (like in the CSS example), but you could likely use the callback parameters `(e, node, id, record)` in order to specifically select which elements you wish to remove.

```
tree2.on('nodeDataBound', function (e, node, id, record) {            
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-type="tree"] > ul > li[data-role="node"] > div[data-role="wrapper"] > span[data-role="checkbox"]`);
    elements.forEach((el) => el.remove());       
});
```